# Using angular on an rails with authentication via Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I have to integrate Angular on a existing app where we use Devise to do the authentication.

We have a user model linked to a profile model.

User model is used for authentication and its Profile model contains users parameters.
We are trying to improve some pages linked to the authenticated user by using Angular.

How can I exchange the current user object between my rails app and my angular application?
The app is pretty big and we can not allow ourselves to implement an authentication via angular.

Thanks for any lead

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this,

[Angular Devise](https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise)

Comment: Yes I did. I pushed a fresh rails template on git: git@github.com:folivi/rails4angular.git
I get nill even when I signed in